# Count Duplicates In Vector In R

Tags: r, duplicates

```
group=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6)
```

I am wishing to generate an output that looks like:

> dup:4
>
> nodup: 2

Basically I want to count how many values are duplicated 'dup' and count how many are not 'nodup'

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option, get the frequency count of values with `table`, convert to logical `> 1` and then do a `table` again

```
table(table(group) > 1)
```

If we  need the label names as 'dup', 'nodup'

```
table(c('nodup', 'dup')[1 + (table(group) > 1)])
#    dup nodup 
#    4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution using `duplicated` + `unique`

```
dup <- sum(duplicated(group))
nodup <- length(unique(group))-dup
```

such that

```
> dup
[1] 4
> nodup
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(group) %>%
    count(group) %>%
    count(dup = n > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a `base R` option:

```
table(rle(sort(group))$lengths > 1)

FALSE  TRUE 
    2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly longer method using base R but more interpretable.

```
repeated_values <- duplicated(group)
table(repeated_values)
```